# How to write PID to file on UNIX

Tags: c, unix, fork, posix, pid

How do I write the PID to file using getpid() function?

I tried casting it to char and writing array of int, neither works.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html
You're most likely not using it correctly

Answer (score 4):

In C, casting from int to char is not enough. Casting changes the way the compiler treats a pointer, how it deference it and how pointer arithmetic is calculated. It does not change the content.

If you want to print an int you must convert it to a string.

you can use:

```
fprintf(fd, "%d", getpid());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int fd;
FILE *somefile;

//text
fprintf(somefile, "%d", getpid()); 

//binary
pid_t pid = getpid();

fwrite(&pid, sizeof(pid), 1, somefile);  

write(fd, &pid, sizeof(pid));
```